# Error CvImagePtr cv_ptr;

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to blend two images the rgb and the depth to look for the shift between.
This is my program, I make it very easy to understand just using the basic of ros programming

```
    #include <ros/ros.h>
    #include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
    #include <opencv/cv.h>
    #include <opencv/highgui.h>
    #include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
    #include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
    
    using namespace cv;
    
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr_rgb;
    
    void imageCallbackrgb(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
    {
    
        //cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr_rgb;
    
        try
        {
            cv_ptr_rgb = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::MONO8);
        }
    
        catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
        {
            ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
            return;
        }
    
    
        //cv::imshow("OpenCV viewer Kinect RGB", cv_ptr_rgb->image);
        
        cvWaitKey(3);
        
    }
    
    
    void imageCallbackdepth(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
    {   
        // convert message from ROS to openCV
        cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr_depth;
        
        try
        {
            cv_ptr_depth = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_16UC1);
    
        }
    
        catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
        {
            ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
            return;
        }
    
        
        //conversion 16UC to 8UC
/*
Conversion Sutffs
*/
    /*
    //*******************************blending two images*************************************
        double alpha = 0.5; double beta; 
        beta = ( 1.0 - alpha );
        Mat dst;
        addWeighted( cv_ptr_rgb->image, alpha, image_8CU, 0.5, 0.5, dst);
        cv::imshow( "Linear Blend", dst );
    //**************************************************************************************
    */
    
        cv::imshow("OpenCV viewer Kinect RGB", cv_ptr_rgb->image);
        //cv::imshow("OpenCV viewer Kinect depth", image8U);
        cvWaitKey(3);
    
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    
    {
        ros::init(argc, argv, "listenerKinectuEye");
        ros::NodeHandle nh;
    
        image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
        
        image_transport::Subscriber subkirgb = it.subscribe("/camera/rgb/image_color", 1, imageCallbackrgb);
        image_transport::Subscriber subkidepth = it.subscribe("/camera/depth_registered/image_raw", 1, imageCallbackdepth);
        
        ROS_INFO("subscribed to Kinect and uEye topics");
    
        ros::spin();
    }
```

And this is the error that I get (sub_node is my executable):

sub_node: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr::operator->() const [with T = cv_bridge::CvImage]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

the error comes from the pointer cv_ptr_rgb  that I use in imageCallbackdepth because even when I try to

```
cv::imshow("OpenCV viewer Kinect RGB", cv_ptr_rgb->image);
```

before doing any blending I get the same error.

How to solve this ? (there is another way to do it?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188450/error-cvimageptr-cv_ptr;/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2014-07-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-31**:
Is this really a ROS problem?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-08-01**:
I don't know you have the same problem ? I found a basic solution you can use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have a race condition with `cv_ptr_rgb`.

You set this global variable in `imageCallbackrgb` and use it in `imageCallbackdepth`.

If the latter callback is called first you get your null-pointer error.

Check if `cv_ptr_rgb` has been set and only then use it.

You could do it like this:

```
if (cv_ptr_rgb != NULL) addWeighted( cv_ptr_rgb->image, alpha, image8U, 0.5, 0.5, dst);
```

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-08-01**:
I don't really understand what should I do exactly ?